# Looping through JSON returning values

Tags: javascript, json

I've json which looks little complex array of json, I want to parse "1238630400000" and "16.10", like this I need all the values. I'm not getting how we can parse all these values.

This is the code I've tried but no luck:

```
for (var key in myJSON.Stocks) {
       alert(myJSON.Stocks[key].stockPrice);

  }

var myJSON = {
    "Stocks": {
        "stockPrice": [
            [1238630400000, 16.10],
            [1238716800000, 16.57],
            [1238976000000, 16.92],
            [1239062400000, 16.43],
            [1239148800000, 16.62],
            [1239235200000, 17.08],
            [1239580800000, 17.17],
            [1239667200000, 16.90],
            [1239753600000, 16.81],
            [1239840000000, 17.35],
            [1239926400000, 17.63],
            [1241049600000, 17.98]
        ]
    }
}
```

Can someone help how can i get all these values?

Comment: That is not JSON, it's an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the values by doing a simple forEach on the stockPrice array

```
myJSON.Stocks.stockPrice.forEach(function(data) { console.log(data[0], data[1]); });
```

Comment: Thanks gabesoft! I want the output in comma separated formatted in singe lime like this                                                                              1238630400000, 16.10, 1238716800000, 16.57,1238976000000,16.92 How can i get like this. I tried this (data[0], ',', data[1], ',') but its not giving expected output

Comment: I got it. I created array and pushed all these values

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way:

```
var csv = myJSON.Stocks.stockPrice.map((o)=>o.join()).join();
console.log(csv);
```